# Ubercart Recurring Payments and Subscriptions:Charge automatically?

Tags: payment-gateways, notifications

I'm using Drupal 6 and Ubercart 6.x-2.7.
In my online store I'm going to manage subscription for the products. Every product can be subscribed for some period of time, weekly, biweekly, monthly, semiannually. I'm going to use PayPal PayFlow Pro and PayPal Website Payments Pro gateways to receive payments. [image]

The issue is here how to manage getting recurring payments through this payment gateways? Any php code or something else?

Here I'm including how this process works:

1. Customer adds required products in his shopping cart.
2. In the cart there is a select-box per every product for subscription(options: just one time, daily, weekly...)
3. Customer checks out from the site paying with Credit/Debit card or PayPal account.

Question: How to charge automatically the fee for subscription in the selected period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this module.

[UC Recurring Payments and Subscriptions](http://drupal.org/project/uc_recurring)

**Features**:

- New/improved API for payment gateways to interface with uc_recurring - see hook_recurring_info().
- Ability to treat a recurring fee as a new order - so it gets access to everything a new order gets at the time of renewal e.g separate invoices, apply roles etc...
- Option for unlimited renewals (ie: renew until canceled).
- Option for recurring payments to be set that same as product price (this means that the recurring payments can be based on adjustments of a products from things like attributes).
- Conditional action support - sending emails on failed renewals.
- Extension API - administrators can configure what will happen on a failed payments, e.g order can be extended and re-attempts as many times as required.

**Take a look at discussions here**

[PayPal community](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Subscriptions-and-recurring/Pre-approved-payments-and-subscriptions/td-p/274040?profile.language=en-gb)

[x.com](https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/recurring-payments-reference-transactions-and-preapproved-payments)

**Please note module is not stable yet**